# Removing pentathletes and digits from string in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Within my column I have several country names that contain numbers and/or parenthesis in their name that I need to remove.

my df,

```
   city
0  Bolivia (Plurinational State of)
1  Switzerland17
```

Expected output df,

```
   city
0  Bolivia
1  Switzerland
```

Comment: Maybe `string.split()[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) combined with a regex:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'city': ['Bolivia (Plurinational State of)', 'Switzerland17']})
df['city'] = df['city'].replace(to_replace='\(.+\)|\d+', value='', regex=True).str.strip()

for e in df['city']:
    print(e)
```

**Output**

```
Bolivia
Switzerland
```

Also you can remove the trailing whitespaces (`str.strip()`).

Comment: thank you for your response but why you make regex = True

Comment: @MuhamadNady because you need to set that parameter True when to_replace is a regular expresion.

Answer (score 1):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'city':['Bolivia (Plurinational State of)','Switzerland17']})
df['city']=df['city'].str.extract(r'([a-zA-Z]+)',expand=True)
print(df)
    city
0   Bolivia
1   Switzerland
```

Comment: thank you this code doing well but what is the meaning of (+) sing here

Comment: `+` to capture 1 or more occurrence..